# Angular2: how to retrieve path array from Router?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-router3, navigatetourl

Do you know that if you want to go to another page you can use the following code?

```
this.router.navigate(['section1', 'section1-children', 'my-page']);
```

Here, as you know, every `string` in the `array` is a path declared in the routing file of the module that loads the related component.

Now, if the component in which I want to use the `navigate` method is agnostic about routing paths, how to retrieve the array of strings corresponding to the full current path?

I would like to have code like the following:

```
let path:Array<string> = this.router.getCurrentArray();
path.push('my-page');
this.router.navigate(path);
```

I have tried to use `ActivatedRoute` service, but the only useful method I found is the following:

```
this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot;
```

that returns an array of Route, not strings.

Do you know a better way to reach my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
this.router.navigate('../' + path);
```

with one of the entries from

```
path = this.router.config[x].path;
```

You should be able to get the full path by

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot.url
```

This only works with `Router` instances injected into the component added by the router for this route.

Comment: The `config` is not what I was looking for. The second way force me to use `navigateByUrl` method instead of `navigate`. Am I right?

Comment: Just saw `this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot;` provides all segments at once, that's better than iterating yourself. `config` is meant to get the available (child) routes, I misinterpreted your question a bit. What if you concatenate the `path` segments from `pathFromRoot` entries? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSegment-class.html#!#path-anchor

Comment: Both ways, yours or mine, in my opinion are "dirty" ways of get the current path. It is weird that there isn't a better way.

Comment: Yup, you're not the first who asks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Summarized from @Günter Zöchbauer  comment:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    let tree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url);
    let g: UrlSegmentGroup = tree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
    let s: UrlSegment[] = g.segments;
    return s.map(a => a.path);
}
```